# Azure Data Factory Geography or Geometry Data types

Tags: azure, spatial, sqlgeography, cross-database, azure-data-factory

I've been trying to set up and Azure Data Factory (unsuccessfully to date). I have 2 Azure SQL databases which are both on the same server (in the same subscription)

In both databases I have a table with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country_Boundaries]
(
    [Id] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Boundary] [geography] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Centroid] [geography] NULL
)
```

I would like to use a data factory to transfer the data from one database table to the same structured table in the second DB.

Do data factories support the Geography/Geometry data type?

I have also looked at using Azure data sync to do this - unfortunately each row in the table is too big for a single data sync transaction (the table contains complex country boundaries using the Geography data type).

Example

```
No of Bytes
Scotland -   55,340,796
NorthernI -  2,149,616
England -    2,126,804
Wales -      705,266
```

The other way I have looked at doing this is using referenced tables but unfortunately referenced tables don't support the Geography/Geometry data type, either.

Comment: Vote for this to get Microsoft to work on it! https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/10508991-support-for-spatial-data-type

Answer (score 1):

I would look at transforming the data into either Well known binary or well known text then pass that into adf and then use a sproc and table type to load the data in batches this gives you the ability to re transform the data ing geography dont forget to include the srid

Answer (score 1):

SQL Geography/Geometry is supported in a limited way that they can only be transferred between SQL databases.
As your source and sink SQL tables have same schema,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country_Boundaries]
(
    [Id] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Boundary] [geography] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Centroid] [geography] NULL
)
```

the only thing you need to do is to create source and sink datasets and Copy activity.  The Copy activity will transfer the 4 column data from source to sink.

Answer (score 0):

> Do data factories support the Geography/Geometry data type?

No, Azure Data Factory does not support spatial types at this time. When selecting a table to sync via the copy wizard, if the table has any spatial columns, you will receive an error:

> Error when processing request: Column: Location,The data type is not supported. activityId: [...]

Or if you select multiple tables, one of which has a spatial column, you will get the error:

> Some tables contain unsupported data type or Object type: [dbo].[Table]. Please use Custom Query to exclude them.

Comment: Update for 2022-11-01:  I've just done a test, and the spatial data types now seem to be fully supported in the Copy Data task.  Note the above answer by David, -- this functionality may only work when both the source and sink are SQL databases.

Comment: @Mike: I have Geography data in sqlServer, I am copying to ADLS Gen2 using Copy activity, and my pipeline failed saying, The data type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography is not supported from the column named Spatial. I think it is not yet supported!

Comment: @subro -- yeah, as noted in David's answer "they can only be transferred between SQL databases", and you are using ADLS.